# How can I insert value to a database to derby in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, derby

I created a form in a JSP to insert data to a database in derby but it doesn't work.

The database name is CUSTOMER. The tables:

```
ID (int), CNAME (varchar), ADDRESS (varchar), PHONENUMBER (varchar)
```

The content of client.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="client" class="database.client" scope="page" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="lightgrey">
    <%
        String ID=request.getParameter("ID");
        String NAME=request.getParameter("CNAME");
        String ADDRESS=request.getParameter("ADDRESS");
        String PHONENUMBER=request.getParameter("PHONENUMBER");
    %>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <table border="0" align="left">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="CNAME" style="background-color:beige"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ADDRESS" style="background-color:beige"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TelNumber</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="PHONENUMBER" style="background-color:beige"/></td>
        </tr>
            <input type="submit" name="OK" onclick="
                <%
               if(NAME!=null && ADDRESS!=null && PHONENUMBER!=null){
                    client.newClient(NAME, ADDRESS, PHONENUMBER);
                }
                %>" value="OK"/>
    </table>
</form>  
</body>
```

The content of client.java.

```
package database;

public class Client implements DatabaseConnection{

private static Connection conn = null;

private static void createConnection(){
try {
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}

private static void closeConnection(){
if (conn != null){
  try {
    conn.close();
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
}
}

public void newClient(String name, String address, String phoneNumber){
    try {
        createConnection();
        String insert="INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(CNAME,ADDRESS, PHONENUMBER) VALUES(?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(insert);
        ps.setString(2, name);
        ps.setString(3, address);
        ps.setString(4, phoneNumber);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}    
}
```

The content of databaseConnection.

```
package database;

public interface DatabaseConnection{
String URL="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Test";
String USER="myusername";
String PASSWORD="mypassword"; 
}
```

**EDIT**

The error message:

```
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Column position '4' is 
outside the allowed range. The columns of ResultSet are '3'.
Org.apache.derby.client.am.ColumnMetaData.checkForValidColumnIndex (unknown 
source)
```

**EDIT2**

```
public void deleteClient(String ID){
    try {
        String delete="DELETE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE ID=?";
        PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(delete);
        ps.setString(1, ID);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: I think I don't get any error. The jsp page refreshes, but no new data in the database.

Comment: did you log is it even calling that save function ?

Comment: No I don't know how can I logging.

Comment: Dollars to donuts there's an exception being thrown in `newClient` that's being totally swallowed by `catch (Exception e) { }`. // rant begins **Don't put empty blocks in `catch` clauses! EVER!** // end rant  Please at least put `e.printStackTrace(System.err);` so you have a clue when something bad happens!

Comment: You should use Servlet to accept form submission and call newClient and return jsp page back to client. Example http://o7planning.org/en/10285/create-a-simple-java-web-application-using-servlet-jsp-and-jdbc

Comment: @KevinAnderson thanks Please put a e.printStackTrace there Lobi

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Column position '4' is outside the allowed range. The columns of ResultSet are '3'.
Org.apache.derby.client.am.ColumnMetaData.checkForValidColumnIndex (unknown source). 
Maybe the problem with ID? No ID in insert command?

Comment: @Lobi Apart from Kevin's comment regarding having e.printStackTrace in the catch, you should move the `ps.close()` method to the finally block of `try catch finally`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your preparedStatement index should start from 1, not from 2, so try as

```
public void newClient(String name, String address, String phoneNumber){
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        createConnection();
        String insert="INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(ID,CNAME,ADDRESS, PHONENUMBER) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(insert);
        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, address);
        ps.setString(3, phoneNumber);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception ex)  {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally  {
        ps.close();
        closeConnection();
    }
}
```

PreparedStatement or Connection close methods should be in the finally part of `try catch finally` block.

Similar to the `closeConnection()` method, you can create another method for closing preparedStatement and call that in the finally block.

**Update 1**

If you are capturing Id in Java, then try as

```
public void newClient(Integer id, String name, String address, String phoneNumber){
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        createConnection();
        String insert="INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(CNAME,ADDRESS, PHONENUMBER) VALUES(?,?,?)";
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(insert);
        ps.setInt(1, id)
        ps.setString(2, name);
        ps.setString(3, address);
        ps.setString(4, phoneNumber);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception ex)  {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally  {
        ps.close();
        closeConnection();
    }
}
```

And in the JSP, modify as

```
if(ID!=null && NAME!=null && ADDRESS!=null && PHONENUMBER!=null){
                    client.newClient(ID, NAME, ADDRESS, PHONENUMBER);
                }
```

Comment: I tried it. Now the error message is: Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: The column 'ID' can not accept NULL.

Comment: is there a id column in the customer table ?

Comment: @Lobi It means the `ID` column is `NOT NULL` in the database table. So you should pass the ID as well if you are populating from the Java code.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: @Lobi you could declare that column to autoincrement http://www.binarytides.com/create-autoincrement-columnfield-in-apache-derby/

Comment: @Lobi If your strategy is to autoincrement, then do not need to pass the value of ID from Java. If that is not the case, then you must change the sequence of preparedStatement to pass from Java.

Comment: Here is my table declaration:
CREATE TABLE customer (
 id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
        , cName VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
 , address VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
 , phoneNumber VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO customer VALUES (1, 'Name', 'Address', 'Phonenumber');

Comment: @Lobi Are you planning to populate your primary key from Java or you would like to populate using AUTOINCREMENT?

Comment: @Lobi I would suggest you should use the strategy to populate using AUTOINCREMENT so that it will be taken care at the database level. itself. I am not sure about syntax of Derby, but try to create the table as `CREATE TABLE customer ( id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) , cName VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL , address VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL , phoneNumber VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL ); `

Comment: @Lobi I happened to see this code from your question `String ID=request.getParameter("ID");` Are you capturing ID value in Java?

Comment: Yes, because I would like to delete records. Here is the code, but unfortunately doesn't work.
 <input type="submit" name="delete" onclick="<%client.deleteClient(ID);%>" value="Delete"/> I made an EDIT2 in my question.

Comment: @Lobi I am not sure about the logic behind delete record. If you are capturing the ID value in Java, then you should pass that value to the table. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Lobi In the `deleteClient` method, you have not added `e.printStackTrace();` and without it would not be possible to know the exceptions or errors.

Comment: In JSP: String ID=request.getParameter("ID");
Pte problem incompatible types: String cannot converted to Integer

Comment: This should be defined as `Integer id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ID"));`

Comment: I changed your suggest.
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
root cause

java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 logs.

Comment: @Lobi I would suggest you should create another question for the errors which you are getting in the JSP.

Comment: Ok, I will create a new question some hours later, and will link the page. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159589/how-can-i-insert-and-delete-value-in-a-database-in-derby-in-jsp