# How can I insert and delete value in a database in derby in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

The history: [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149892/how-can-i-insert-value-to-a-database-to-derby-in-jsp/)

The problem is I cannot delete customer from the database. I can create a new customer, but if I leave blank the fields it create an empty record in the database but I create an if criterium.

The client.java:

```
public class client implements DatabaseConnection{

private static Connection conn = null;

private static void createConnection(){
try {
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}

private static void closeConnection(){
if (conn != null){
  try {
    conn.close();
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
}
}

public List clientList(){
    createConnection();
    List list=new ArrayList();
    try {
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customer");
        while(rs.next()){
            list.add(rs.getString("CNAME"));
            list.add(rs.getString("ADDRESS"));
            list.add(rs.getString("PHONENUMBER"));
        }
        stmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    return list;
}

public void newClient(String name, String address, String phoneNumber) 
throws SQLException{
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        createConnection();
        String insert="INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(CNAME,ADDRESS, PHONENUMBER) 
VALUES(?,?,?)";
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(insert);
        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, address);
        ps.setString(3, phoneNumber);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    finally {
        ps.close();
        closeConnection();
    }
}
public void deleteClient(String ID){
    try {
        createConnection();
        String delete="DELETE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE ID=?";
        PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(delete);
        ps.setString(1, ID);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}

}
```

The index.jsp:

```
<jsp:useBean id="client" class="database.client" scope="page" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="lightgrey">
    <%
        String ID=request.getParameter("ID");
        String NAME=request.getParameter("CNAME");
        String ADDRESS=request.getParameter("ADDRESS");
        String PHONENUMBER=request.getParameter("PHONENUMBER");
    %>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <table border="0" align="left">
        <th colspan="2" align="center" style="color: brown">Field</th>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="CNAME" style="background-
color:beige"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address?</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ADDRESS" style="background-
color:beige"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PhoneNumber:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="PHONENUMBER" style="background-
color:beige"/></td>
        </tr>
            <input type="submit" name="OK" onclick="
                <%
               if(NAME!=null && ADDRESS!=null && PHONENUMBER!=null){
                    client.newClient(NAME, ADDRESS, PHONENUMBER);
                }
                %>" value="OK"/>
            <input type="submit" name="Cancel" onclick="
               <%
               //nothing
               %>" value="Cancel"/>
            <input type="submit" name="Delete" onclick="
<%client.deleteClient(ID);%>" value="Delete"/>
    </table>
    <table border="2">
        <th colspan="4" align="center" bgcolor="orange">Clients</th>
        <tr bgcolor="silver" align="center">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>PhoneNumber</td>
        </tr>
        <%
            List list=client.clientList();
            Iterator it=list.iterator();

            while(it.hasNext()){
                out.print("<tr bgcolor='lightgreen'>");
                out.print("<td>");
                NAME=(String)it.next();
                out.print("<input type='radio' name='ID' value="+NAME+"/>");
                out.print("</td>");
                out.print("<td>");
                out.print(NAME);
                out.print("</td>");
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    out.print("<td>");
                    out.print(it.next());
                    out.print("</td>");
                }
            out.print("</tr>");

            }
        %>
    </table>
</form>  
</body>
</html>
```

If I leave empty the fields and click OK the following error message appears:
    Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: No actual connection.

If no connection how can create an empty record?

And:

```
Severe:   java.lang.NullPointerException at: client.java PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(delete);
```

**EDIT**
The new error:
    Severe: java.sql.SQLDataException: Invalid string format for INTEGER.

Comment: What about including a createConnection() and closeConnection() in all your methods that access the database?

Comment: Has the insertion of records issue resolved? Only remaining issue is deletion?

Comment: Approximately yes, only the problem is delete. AND a small problem with insert to I can insert empty record, not watch the if(NAME!=null && ADDRESS!=null && PHONENUMBER!=null)

Comment: @Lobi First we will discuss the deletion issue. What does the following return in the `deleteClient` method `e.printStackTrace();` Paste the output by editing your question.

Comment: I added createConnection(), because I forgot to add. Now:
Severe: java.sql.SQLDataException: Invalid string format for INTEGER.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not setting the ID in the list

```
while(rs.next()){
        list.add(rs.getString("ID")); // Add this
        list.add(rs.getString("CNAME"));
        list.add(rs.getString("ADDRESS"));
        list.add(rs.getString("PHONENUMBER"));
    }
```

Without ID in the list , you wont be able to access the same from the jsp and the same wont be available when you call the delete method.

Another thing is make sure that the ID is string and not int . Usually we keep the key (i.e ID here ) as integer.

Comment: I tried it, the result: HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
root cause

java.util.NoSuchElementException

Answer (score 0):

I understand from the previous question where you defined ID as integer, so you should use setInt instead of setString, try as

```
public void deleteClient(Integer id){

    try {

        createConnection();
        String delete="DELETE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE ID=?";
        PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(delete);
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        ps.close();
        closeConnection();
    }
}
```

Id is an integer in the database field where you defined it has a primary key.

**Update 1**

Use the following in your index.jsp to convert String to int, pass idNum to your method.

```
 Integer idNum = null;
 String id = request.getParameter("ID");
    if(id != null) {
        try {
            System.out.println("String Id value --> "+id.trim());
            idNum = Integer.parseInt(id.trim());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I changed to: (client.java) public void deleteClient(Integer ID) and ps.setInt(1, ID); and (index.jsp) Integer ID=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ID")); changed string to int.
Now: HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error, org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Comment: Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Comment: Severe:   java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
Severe:   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Bob/"

Comment: @Lobi By the way "Bob" is a string, you should use a number for ID column.

Comment: I have three column in the table: Name, Address, PhoneNumber. 
At the beginning of each line there is a radio button. I click one of them and click Delete button. How can I add 'ID' column?

Comment: @Lobi I repeat what I mentioned in the previous question. If are not sure about populating ID in the table, use this approach. `CREATE TABLE customer ( id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) , cName VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL , address VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL , phoneNumber VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL ); `

Comment: Basically, your problem with the delete is with the setString, so use setInt as it is expecting an int value rather than a string value.

Comment: I changed yet the SQL statement. Now ID is integer but the problem is the same. How can I cange everything to setInt?

Comment: @Lobi I have updated my answer. You must provide the full error stack from e.printStackTrace(); to help you further. Before `ps.setInt(1, id);` do a  System.out.println("id  "+id);

Comment: I rolled back everything. Too many changes I made and the code was totally unreadable. Now I use that code what it is my original question. Error message (full): https://ibb.co/hjFAtF

Comment: @Lobi  Before ps.setInt(1, id); do a System.out.println("id "+id);

Comment: now, I have ps.setString. 
Info:   ID: null
Info:   ID: Bob/

Comment: @Lobi Id is null or Bob?

Comment: @Lobi The problem is precisely is this, whether it is null or Bob, it cannot be null or Bob. Id should be an integer and cannot be null. You need to sort it out.

Comment: First, when no radio button selected, is null. When I select somebody it changes to his name for example: Bob. I don't know why appears a '/' symbol after the name.

Comment: Oh I found it. I used what @John Thomas wrote. I completed the clientList() method in client.java. AND I made a new column in index.jsp page, so now the table has 5 columns: the radio button selection column, ID,Name,Address and PhoneNumber. So now the  System.out.println("id "+id) when I select somebody the value will be his ID number. But the '/' symbol still here and still dont work the delete method. I make a new question please stay with me. Thanks the help!

Comment: Here is the new question. I do a ** .... ** to see what changed.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163730/how-can-i-insert-and-delete-value-in-a-database-in-derby-in-jsp-3

Comment: @Lobi You create a question with the problem you are facing with radio buttons, the one which you have created is almost similar to this.

Comment: Similar but not equal. Unfortunately I still dont know what is the problem. Why the insert works and why doesnt work the delete. And why insert empty records if in the if statement there is a limitation.