# How can I insert and delete value in a database in derby in JSP? [3]

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

The history:
[History I.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149892/how-can-i-insert-value-to-a-database-to-derby-in-jsp/)
[History II.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159589/how-can-i-insert-and-delete-value-in-a-database-in-derby-in-jsp)

So the problem is still here. If I select somebody and press the delete button, not to delete from database else a new empty record created.

The client.java:

```
public class client implements DatabaseConnection{

private static Connection conn = null;

private static void createConnection(){
try {
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}

private static void closeConnection(){
if (conn != null){
  try {
    conn.close();
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
}
}

public List clientList(){
    createConnection();
    List list=new ArrayList();
    try {
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customer");
        while(rs.next()){
            **list.add(rs.getString("ID"));**
            list.add(rs.getString("CNAME"));
            list.add(rs.getString("ADDRESS"));
            list.add(rs.getString("PHONENUMBER"));
        }
        stmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    return list;
}

public void newClient(String name, String address, String phoneNumber) 
throws SQLException{
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        createConnection();
        String insert="INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(CNAME,ADDRESS, PHONENUMBER) 
VALUES(?,?,?)";
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(insert);
        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, address);
        ps.setString(3, phoneNumber);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    finally {
        ps.close();
        closeConnection();
    }
}
public void deleteClient(String ID){
    try {
        createConnection();
        String delete="DELETE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE ID=?";
        PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(delete);
        ps.setString(1, ID);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    **finally {
    closeConnection();
}**
}

}
```

The index.jsp:

```
<jsp:useBean id="client" class="database.client" scope="page" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="lightgrey">
    <%
        String ID=request.getParameter("ID");
        String NAME=request.getParameter("CNAME");
        String ADDRESS=request.getParameter("ADDRESS");
        String PHONENUMBER=request.getParameter("PHONENUMBER");
    %>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <table border="0" align="left">
        <th colspan="2" align="center" style="color: brown">Field</th>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="CNAME" style="background-
color:beige"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address?</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ADDRESS" style="background-
color:beige"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PhoneNumber:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="PHONENUMBER" style="background-
color:beige"/></td>
        </tr>
            <input type="submit" name="OK" onclick="
                <%
               if(NAME!=null && ADDRESS!=null && PHONENUMBER!=null){
                    client.newClient(NAME, ADDRESS, PHONENUMBER);
                }
                %>" value="OK"/>
            <input type="submit" name="Cancel" onclick="
               <%
               //nothing
               %>" value="Cancel"/>
            <input type="submit" name="Delete" onclick="
<%client.deleteClient(ID);%>" value="Delete"/>
    </table>
    <table border="2">
        <th colspan="4" align="center" bgcolor="orange">Clients</th>
        <tr bgcolor="silver" align="center">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            **<td>ID</td>**
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>PhoneNumber</td>
        </tr>
        <%
            List list=client.clientList();
            Iterator it=list.iterator();

            while(it.hasNext()){
                out.print("<tr bgcolor='lightgreen'>");
                out.print("<td>");
                **ID**=(String)it.next();
                out.print("<input type='radio' name='ID' value="+**ID**+"/>");
                out.print("</td>");
                out.print("<td>");
                out.print(**ID**);
                out.print("</td>");
                for (int i = 0; i < **3**; i++) {
                    out.print("<td>");
                    out.print(it.next());
                    out.print("</td>");
                }
            out.print("</tr>");

            }
        %>
    </table>
</form>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your Java code is ok, but on the other side, your jsp code looks like uuugh...You can use something like `ajax` to do those operations....I hope that this is an student app instead of a production ready app...I can help you, now I need you to `right click` on your `Delete` button and choose `Inspect element`, then in the `Dom Explorer` copy the highlighted html and add it to your question...

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new Servlet (Delete Servlet) and pass the ID in url and handle it in new jsp page ...You can change your code likethis :

**Index JSP:**

```
<a href="DeleteServlet?id=<%=Integer.toString(person.getID())%>">Delete</a>
```

**Delete Servlet :** Updated

```
@WebServlet(name = "DeleteServlet", urlPatterns = {"/DeleteServlet"})
public class DeleteServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CurdOperationsImpl.class.getName());

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String ID = request.getParameter("id");


            int id = Integer.parseInt(PersonId);

            deleteClient(id); // add your own code

            out.println("<h2 style='color: green'>Person Deleted Sucessfully.</h2>");
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }else {

        }
    }
```

Bonus : get this my ugly Servlet-JSP-Mysql project is ready to use [Github link](https://github.com/Coder-ACJHP/Personal-Information-MVC)
I hope this help you.

Comment: Hello
How can I create DeleteServlet? In the Web Pages -> index.jsp?

Comment: Create separate servlet class not in index.JSP .

Comment: In the source packages folder? New -> Java package: servlet? AND in the servlet package: new -> Servlet?

Comment: Yes , look at the link in end of the answer. (Github Link)

Comment: Sorry, Im too new for servlet. I copied what you write, 
It cannot find: - CurdOperationsImpl, - PersonId, and problem with }else {
            
        }

Comment: @Lobi "CurdOperationsImpl" and "PersonId" these my own method and object , delete these and add your own code like in answer.It's very easy just pass the ID with url who you want to delete it and handle it from servlet.

Comment: I have a problem with deleteClient(). What should I do? I copied your code. In my client.java (see it in my question) has a method deleteClient(). Should I copy to your code?

Comment: Could you make the whole code what should I copy to my DeleteServlet.java?

Comment: Can I put a method in doGet? AND in the index.jps where can I put your code? On the top? First line?

Comment: See @Lobi Servlet is same normal Java class but it using in web projects so you can add your methods into doGet. I already putted it to you

Comment: OMG! you tryng to create method in the method! just delete name of method = "public void deleteClient()".How you writed your delete method codes in index.jsp just copy and past them into doGET method.

Comment: Please don't ask another question..I answered your all questions and gived you full project for example.

Comment: Only one more answer please: how can I add your linked example project in netbeans? I downloaded the full zip, unzipped, but no world icon when i open the folder.